# Stripe Elements Google Web Font Not Working

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I can't get Stripe Elements to use Google's Lato. I know there are other questions similar to this one but I don't see anything that applies. I tried fixing this for a while with no luck

```
var windowHash = getWindowHash();
var stripe = Stripe(stripePubKey);
var elements = stripe.elements({
  fonts: [
    {
      family: "'Lato'",
      src: 'local("Lato"), local("lato"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format("woff2")',
      weight: 300,
      style: "normal",
      unicodeRange: "U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF"
    }
  ]
});

var card = elements.create('card', {
  iconStyle: 'solid',
  hidePostalCode: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#3cacce',
      color: '#424B54',
      lineHeight: '36px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: '"Lato", sans-serif',
      fontSize: '13pt',
      fontStyle: "normal",
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#969696'
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      iconColor: '#b32903',
      color: '#b32903',
    }
  },
  classes: {
    focus: 'is-focused',
    empty: 'is-empty',
  },
});
```

And somewhere else:

```
card.mount('.cardElement');
```

Any tips on how I can get this to display properly?

**Update:**

Found the problem! I was trying to load in Lato Light, but because the normal Lato was added, using 300 wight didn't work. Adding the Lato Light font made it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Reason:** Have to use `latin` link and unicode range. **Not the `latin-ext`** [font face](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato) for Lato font (latin and latin-ext)

**Use the following fonts parameters**

```
fonts: [
    {
      family: '"Lato"',
      src: 'local("Lato Regular"), local("Lato-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/MDadn8DQ_3oT6kvnUq_2r_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format("woff2")',
      weight: 300,
      style: 'normal',
      unicodeRange: 'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: great! except the weight doesn't appear to work for me, always the same result no matter what i set it to, but oh well, small vicotry...

Comment: James, you have to use the correct font weight font type. I used Lato Light, there is also Lato Regular and a few others for bolder and lighter.

Comment: I'd be curious to know when these URLs expire.

Answer (score 13):

You can now use the cssSrc option:

```
let stripe = Stripe('pk_test_JYjfAwsv9ODbL7mm1qObrIXZ')
let elements = stripe.elements({
  fonts: [
    {
      cssSrc: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600'
    }
  ]
})
```

Then you can reference it in in the style options when you create the card:

```
let card = elements.create('card', {
  style: {
    base: {
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'            
    }
  }
})
card.mount('#card-element')
```

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference

Comment: This is definitely the easier solution since they created it.

Comment: Ahhh. +1 for setting the `fontFamily`. This is what I forgot to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Elements component you can specify cssSrc option to import external fonts like so.. (the code is written in typescript)

Outside the component

```
const ELEMENT_OPTIONS: StripeElementsOptions = {
 fonts: [
    {
     cssSrc:
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;900",
    },
  ],
};
```

Inside the component

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}>
  <StripeCheckoutForm />
</Elements>
```